# Что означает <?= ?

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте, для сайта пишу шаблонизатор и за основу взял из вот этой [статьи](http://myrusakov.ru/php-template.html).

проблема следующая, есть вот такой шаблончик:

```
<ul>
    <? foreach ($this->menu AS $link => $name){ ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $link?>"><?= $name?></a>
    </li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

в строчке

```
<a href="<?= $link?>"><?= $name?></a>
```

я никак не могу понять что значит "`=`", "`<?`" понятно начинается php код, но что за равно стоит ?

Без него переменные не работают

Comment: Поправочка предыдущего оратора

Comment: ... и до мышей, до мышей тоже доберемся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это короткая запись означает <? echo $var; ?>

Comment: Поправочка предыдущего аратора <?php echo $var; ?>

Answer (score 2):

Ага, давайте еще заглянем в словарь и узнаем, кто такой оратор, а заодно вспомним, что в php открывающим тегом может быть как <?php ?>, так и <? ?>, <% %> и даже <script language="php"><script>.